# Question about ggplot, for loop and marrangeGrob. Does anyone know how to fix the code when all plots are the same?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, graph

[Graphs are printed the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GRBZ.png)
I have tried many ways but all my plots printed out the same. When I tried using the for-loop and ggplot (without marrangeGrob), the graphs are different but they are printed out separate, while I want it to print out 4 graphs on each page. Does anyone know how to do it? 
Here is the written code:

```
char_var <- select_if(train,is.character)
#names(char_var)
library(gridExtra)
plot_char <- list()
for (i in 1:43 ) {
        plot_char[[length(plot_char)+1]]= ggplot(data=train,mapping= aes(x= char_var[,i], y = SalePrice)) + xlab(i)+ geom_boxplot()  
}

marrangeGrob(grobs = plot_char, nrow = 2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might want `aes_string(x= char_var[,i], y = "SalePrice")` instead of your current `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. When I changed to aes_string, it said "Error: More than one expression parsed". A suggestion to fix this error is changing back to aes()